# Equilateral hexagon with parallel sides

Tags: geometry

The problem states:
Let $A = (0,0)$ and $B = (b,2)$ be points on the coordinate plane. Let $ABCDEF$ be a convex equilateral hexagon such that $\angle FAB = 120^\circ, \overline{AB}\parallel \overline{DE}, \overline{BC}\parallel \overline{EF,} \overline{CD}\parallel \overline{FA}$, and the y-coordinates of its vertices are distinct elements of the set $\{0,2,4,6,8,10\}$. The area of the hexagon can be written in the form m\sqrt {n}, where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers and n is not divisible by the square of any prime. Find $m + n.$

Clearly the y-coordinate of $F$ is $4$. With complex numbers it is easy to see that $F =\left(-\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}, 4\right)$ $B= \left(\dfrac{10\sqrt{3}}{3},2 \right)$.

Thus the length of the sides of the hexagon is $4 \sqrt{7/3}$, then $FB = 4\sqrt{7}$. We must also have the height from A to FB is simply $2\sqrt{7/3}$. Clearly DEC and FAB are congruent and EFBC is a parallelogram therefore the final area is just:
$2\sqrt{7/3}(4\sqrt{7}) + 4\sqrt{7} \cdot 4\sqrt{7/3} =56\sqrt{3}$.

But the correct answer is 51, what is wrong with this?

Thanks

Comment: An alternative way to compute the area of the parallelogram is to split it into two triangles. The area of a triangle with vertices $\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ may then be computed using the formula $\frac{1}{2}\text{Im}[(z_1-z_3)\overline{(z_2-z_3)}]$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Regular hexagon]

Area ABF = Area DEC, and for each of these triangles, the area = $\frac{1}{2}x^2sin 120^{\circ}$, or $\frac{1}{2}(4\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}})^2 \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.  The area of both of these triangles, then, is $56\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.

Remaining is the parallelogram BCEF.  The base is the length of FB, or $4\sqrt{7}$.  The height is the perpendicular distance between the lines, given by $\frac{\vert{b_2 - b_1}\vert}{\sqrt{m^2 + 1}}$, or $\frac{22\sqrt{3}}{3\sqrt{7}}$.  The parallelogram's area, then, is $88\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  Adding it all together yields an area of $48\sqrt{3}$.

Note, I think it's much simpler to compute the area of ABDE and the other two triangles.  The x-coordinate of B is $\sqrt{x^2 - 4}$, or $10\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  Then the area of ABDE is 8 $\times$ $10\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  The total area of the other two triangles BCD and EFA is 8 $ \times$ $8\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$, yielding a total area of $48\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: It's worth pointing out where the mistake in the OP's calculation enters in: The perpendicular distance is $\frac{22\sqrt{3}}{3\sqrt{7}}$ rather than $2\sqrt{7/3}$.